# Enlarging JFrame/JPanel Programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

I have been working on a Java 2D game and halfway through I noticed that my screen and sprites are too small. Enlarging them by hand would be a pain.

Is it possible to enlarge a JFrame or JPanel and all of it's contents when using Java 2D to draw images to a Panel?

Comment: Take a look at [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) which allows you to adjust the scaling (amongst other things) of the `Graphics2D` object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics2D is providing the image re-size feature as follows :

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
```

According to some articles, if you want to increase the re-sized image quality, you can add the RenderingHints as follows :

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Other links worth checking out:

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/algorithms-recursion/818-change-size-image.html

http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/resize-images-in-java-preserving-image-quality/

http://ajax911.com/resize-images-java-java2d-method/